# Using GoogleMock to mock an instance created by code under test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have create an interface (here's an example):

```
class DataStream
{
    virtual std::string read(std::string terminator) = 0;
    virtual size_t write(std::string data) = 0;
};
```

For which there exists a concrete implementation, such as:

```
class SerialDataStream : public DataStream
{
public:
    // NOTE: This constructor will throw an exception if the
    // serial port cannot be opened.
    SerialDataStream(string port, int baudrate);
    std::string read(std::string terminator);
    size_t write(std::string data);
}
```

And the interface is used, for example:

```
class SomeThing
{
public:
    SomeThing(std::shared_ptr<DataStream> stream);
}
```

Using GoogleMock, testing the SomeThing class is fairly straight forward, all you need to do is create a mock implementation for the interface, for example:

```
class MockDataStream : public DataStream
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(read, size_t(std::vector<uint8_t>&));
    MOCK_METHOD1(write, size_t(std::vector<uint8_t>&));
}
```

Where the test would look something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<MockDataStream> mock_stream(nullptr);
mock_stream = std::make_shared<MockDataStream>();
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_stream, write("START")).Times(AtLeast(1));
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_stream, read("\n")).Times(AtLeast(1));
SomeThing some_thing = SomeThing(mock_stream);
```

Which is pretty cool as it easily allows me to unittest how the SomeThing class uses the DataStream interface.

However, there also exists some code whose job it is to create new (concrete) DataStream objects and I'm finding using GoogleMock to test this a little more tricky. For example, here is a snippet of some code that needs to be tested:

```
std::shared_ptr<DataStream> datastream(nullptr);

// Try and open the serial port:
try
{
    std::shared_ptr<SerialDataStream> serialstream =
        std::make_shared<SerialDataStream>("/dev/tty99", 115200);
}
catch (...) 
{
    // Returns a nullptr
    return datastream;
}

// Check if there is a known device on the other end:
datastream = std::static_pointer_cast<DataStream>(serialstream);
if (!device_is_connected(datastream))
{
    datastream = nullptr;
}
return datastream;
```

I'm struggling to find an effective method to test this code with GoogleMock:

1. I would like to mock the constructor (of SerialDataStream) so it throws an exception and the failure path is executed as expected.
2. I would like to test the successful path where the private API "device_is_connected" uses the newly created datastream object.

Is it the case that I have no option other than to create a fake SerialDataStream implementation and use dependency injection to test the code which creates concrete DataStream objects?

If this is the case, I'll just have to make the API "device_is_connected" public so I can simply test it with a mock implementation of the interface (as above) to test, for example:

```
datastream.write("DISCOVER");
string response = datastream.read("\n");
if (discovery_ok(response))
{ 
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm fairly certain I've answered my own question and will have no option but to fake the SerialDataStream class and use dependency injection, and make private APIs public and simply test them via GoogleMock, but I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way I could/should be doing things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code snipped you provided, I found myself asking:
What exactly should the function do? It seems like it
(1) creates a SerialDataStream and
(2) checks if a device is connected.

You may could break the function into two (individually testable) parts.
Still there is the question on how to handle the `std::shared_ptr<SerialDataStream> serialstream = std::make_shared<SerialDataStream>("/dev/tty99", 115200);` - at some point you will need to tackle the (hidden) **new** there.

And I agree with you - dependency injection might be the solution there. Turning whatever class or function ends up responsible for creating into a template class/function would allow to write you (e.g.)

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<DataStream> createDatastream()
{
    std::shared_ptr<DataStream> datastream(nullptr);
    std::shared_ptr<T> datastream = std::make_shared<T>("/dev/tty99", 115200);
    return datastream;
}
```

And then instantiate the class/function with `SerialDataStream` in your application, while using a `MockDataStream` to test the function(s).

Comment: Yes that's exactly correct, I made the "checks device connected" to be a public static API so it is testable.

Comment: I really like your suggestion in regards to the template, that's a neat solution and I will have a play around with that, thanks a lot!